# Feature Importance keras regressionmodel

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to extract the feature importance or saliency map from my keras regression model:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import shap
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance

# Load data (modify as needed)
s_data = np.array([
     [1.0, 0.0, np.nan, 0.0],
     [2.0, 0.0, np.nan, 2.0],
     [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0]
 ])


# Load phenotype labels as a NumPy array (modify as needed)
 labels = np.array([
     [7.],
     [9.],
     [2.] ])

s_data[np.isnan(s_data)] = -1

# Split data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(s_data, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Standardize the input features 
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Define a deep learning model
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],)),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')  
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')  

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
```

I have tried to use the eli5 library:

```
import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance

perm = PermutationImportance(model, random_state=1).fit(X_train,y_train)
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X_train.columns.tolist())

# Evaluate the model on the test set
test_loss = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(f'Test Loss: {test_loss}')
```

But it raises this error:

> TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000002B1ABA41448> does not.

I also tried to write my own permutation features importance function:

```
n_permutations = 100  # Number of permutations to perform
feature_importances = np.zeros(X_test.shape[1])
print (feature_importances.max())

for _ in range(n_permutations):
    shuffled_X_test = X_test.copy()
    np.random.shuffle(shuffled_X_test)  # Permute the feature values
    shuffled_loss = model.evaluate(shuffled_X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    importance = test_loss - shuffled_loss
    feature_importances += importance

# Normalize feature importances
feature_importances /= n_permutations
# Print feature importances
print("Feature Importances:")
for i, importance in enumerate(feature_importances):
    print(f"SNP{i+1}: {importance:.4f}")
```

But this gives me the same value for each data point.

How can I extract the feature important for a regression model?

Answer (score 2):

With permutation tests, one feature is taken at a time and shuffled. In your implementation, all features are being shuffled each time and the result is being broadcast back to all features. Here's an untested modification of your code, which shows how I'd modify it to permute one feature at a time:

```
n_permutations = 100  # Number of permutations to perform
feature_importances = np.zeros(X_test.shape[1])
print (feature_importances.max())

for feature_index in range(len(feature_importances)):
    print('Running permutations for feature:', feature_index)
    for _ in range(n_permutations):
        shuffled_X_test = X_test.copy()
        
        #Shuffle the current feature
        #Keep other features the same
        np.random.shuffle(shuffled_X_test[:, feature_index])
        shuffled_loss = model.evaluate(shuffled_X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
        importance = test_loss - shuffled_loss
        feature_importances[feature_index] += importance
    #Average all the permutation tests for the current feature
    feature_importances[feature_index] /= n_permutations

# Print feature importances
print("Feature Importances:")
for i, importance in enumerate(feature_importances):
    print(f"SNP{i+1}: {importance:.4f}")
```

Here is a more complete example, but using PyTorch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78052896/21896093